# Why is this valid: $2 \int^{\sqrt t}_0 \frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi}} e^{-u^2/2} du = \frac 1 {\sqrt {2 \pi}} \int^t_0 e^{-s/2}s^{-1/2}ds$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Could someone explain why the following change of variable is valid?:

$$2 \int^{\sqrt t}_0 \frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi}} e^{-u^2/2} du = \frac 1 {\sqrt {2 \pi}} \int^t_0 e^{-s/2}s^{-1/2}ds$$

Using the substitution method I've been used to, I can write $s = u^2$ which implies $\frac {ds} {du} = 2u$. So $ds = 2u (du)$. But $2u (du)$ is not to be found in the integral, so obviously $ds/u$ is substituted for $2(du)$. However why is this permissible ?

Comment: It is du that you have to replace in the lhs, isn't ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change $du$ to $ds$...

You got $$\frac{ds}{du}=2u.$$

Then, what we want is to get the following form :
$$du=F(s)ds$$
for a function $F$.

Since 
$$s=u^2,s\ge0, u\ge0,$$
we have
$$u=\sqrt s=s^{1/2}.$$
So, we have
$$\frac{ds}{du}=2u=2s^{1/2}.$$

Hence, the first integral will be
$$2\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-s/2}\cdot \frac{1}{2s^{1/2}}ds.$$

EDIT : 
$$\int_{g(0)}^{g(t)}f(u)du=\int_{0}^{t}f(g(s))g^\prime(s)ds$$
where
$$f(u)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-u^2/2},g(s)=\sqrt s.$$

Comment: You are welcome! my pleasure.

Comment: Sorry to bother you once more, but why dont we write $du = 2s^{1/2}$ then we get $\int f(s) \cdot ds/du = F(s)$ (right)? - and then evaluate for new limits. We are we multiplying by $(ds/du)^{-1}$ ?

Comment: No, it is not correct. You want to change a variable $u$ to $s$, right? we have $ds/du=2u.$ so, how can we get $du=2s^{1/2}$? Remember that $ds$ and $du$ have to be in the same equation.

Comment: We get $ds/du = 2s^{1/2}$. So now our integral is in the form $\int f(s) \cdot \frac 1 {2s^{1/2}} ds$. To to use our rule $\int f(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) = F(g(x))$ we must have $\frac 1 {2s^{1/2}} = ds/du$, which it is not ?

Comment: We have $ds/du=2s^{1/2}\iff du=ds/2s^{1/2}.$ so, you can set this into the first integral. This is all we do.

Comment: But we cannot calculate with $ds/du$ like it was a fraction. These are only symbols. We must bring the integral into the form shown above ? If not, please tell how you justify your manipulation.

Comment: A good point. see here. You'll learn a lot. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-dy-dx-not-a-ratio

Comment: So we are not doing regular substitution rule like the one I'm mentioning above ? And does your method has a name ?

Comment: Technically, we can 'set $du=ds/2s^{1/2}$ in the first integral'. This is all we do. This is not substitution. We just change a variable from $u$ to $s$. In the process to change it, we can treat $du=ds/2s^{1/2}$ 'as a fraction'. This is how we solve integrals. So, I think first you need to know how to solve it, and know why we can do like this. In short, you cannot find the value of integrals in your way. Just learn and try it.

Comment: It makes sense, although I've never solved integrals like this. In Calculus courses, I've only worked with well-known rules like integration by substitution and parts. However where can I read about your method formally ? Does this method has a name ? Where is it proved ?

Comment: Well, many many textbooks... You can go to library, or book shop or internet... Just find information. There are tons of sites. so, google "substitution method" (I said this is not substitution, which means your way is not substitution, sorry it may confuse you) I think you don't really understand how to use substitution method. Just read a book or a site carefully and try to solve an easy quetion...Good luck!

Comment: Well, it requires a proof that you can substitute $du = ds/F(s)$ for some function $F$, change the limit of the integral and then everything works. The substitution method is proved rigorous here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution
Just because one solves some questions using your strategy works doesn't mean it is true.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you really want to say.

Comment: Is this the version of integration by substitution you are using ?: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution.
If yes, can you write our integral as $\int^a_b f(g(x))g'(x) dx$ and apply this integration rule to solve the problem ? If this is not the integration rule you are using, please provide a link to it - just a single webpage where it is stated formally.

Comment: @user111854 : see an edit in my answer.

Comment: Yes, this is totally right. We are using the substitution rule in reverse to get the answer. How come the other way of doing it provide the same answer ?

Comment: What is 'the other way'?